# Propel: selecting columns from aliased join tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, orm, propel

I have the following two tables:

```
  table_a:
    id_table_a: { type: integer, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true, required: true }
    name:       { type: varchar(255) }
    id_table_b: { type: integer, foreignTable: table_b, foreignReference: id_table_b }

  table_b: 
    id_table_b: { type: integer, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true, required: true }
    value_1:    { type: varchar(255) }
    value_2:    { type: integer }
```

and I would like to build SQL query using select method to skip hydration, also using aliases on joined tables:

```
 TableAQuery::create()
            ->useTableBQuery('a')
                // some filters methods
            ->endUse()
            ->useTableBQuery('b')
                // some filters methods
            ->endUse()
            ->select(array('a.value_1', 'b.value_2'))
            ->find();
```

Now here is the problem. Propel consantly keep changing `a` and `b` aliases to `table_b` generating incorrect SQL like this:

```
SELECT table_b.value_1 AS "a.value_1", table_b.value_2 AS "b.value_2" FROM `table_a`
LEFT JOIN `table_b` `a` ON (table_a.id_table_b=a.id_table_b) 
LEFT JOIN `table_b` `b` ON (table_a.id_table_b=b.id_table_b)
```

instead of

```
SELECT a.value_1 AS value_1, b.value_2 AS value_2 FROM `table_a` 
LEFT JOIN `table_b` `a` ON (table_a.id_table_b=a.id_table_b) 
LEFT JOIN `table_b` `b` ON (table_a.id_table_b=b.id_table_b)
```

How can I deal with that? I use Propel 1.6.9

UPDATE

I also checked propel 1.7.1, no difference.

Comment: Interesting problem, and I don't know the answer; perhaps it is a Propel bug. Do you still need an answer for it? I'll add a bounty on it, if you do. Ping me at @halfer, if so.

Comment: @halfer It would be nice if you could help bring some atention to this topic. I work with Propel almost every day and it's not the first time I get stuck because of this issue.

Comment: I think I have the same issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20127660/propel-translating-the-wrong-table-names Do you know if there has been a bug filed?

Comment: @KarasQ, let me know how you get on with jchamberlain's suggestion.

Comment: @halfer jchamberlain's suggestion produces the same results as in my example.

Comment: @KarasQ: looks like you're making progress, great stuff. What might be useful here is if you could create the smallest possible tarball that illustrates this problem, likely using SQLite. That can be used here so readers can try to get it working without warnings, and also possibly on the Propel bug tracker.

Comment: @halfer In final result I think that not a Propel bug was the case but wrong column name style, so it won't be necessary. Thanks for your support

Comment: You're welcome, glad you fixed it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you change it to this?

```
TableAQuery::create()
        ->useTableBQuery('a')
            // some filters methods
        ->endUse()
        ->useTableBQuery('b')
            // some filters methods
        ->endUse()
        //->select(array('a.value_1', 'b.value_2'))
        ->addAsColumn('a.value_1', 'a.value_1')
        ->addAsColumn('b.value_2', 'b.value_2')
        ->find();
```

Caveat: I'm not a Propel user. <s>I'm just wondering if the auto-generated `useXXXQuery()` is setting the table alias on the same relation both times, or something like that.</s>

As in the query above, replace your `select()` with the two `addAsColumn()` statements. It's a bit of a hack, but I think it achieves your desired result.

I just spent a while reading the Propel source code, and I've concluded that Propel 1 is not built to use different aliases on the same table joined multiple times, as you attempt. In `ModelCriteria.php`, the use of `$column->getFullyQualifiedName` ensures that the full name (table.column) is used in the select for joined tables, regardless of alias. (See https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/blob/7ddb0956b699343d33ce0c94043fa5970cc719c1/runtime/lib/query/ModelCriteria.php#L2082.) I expect this is indeed a bug.

If the `addAsColumn()` method is used instead of `select()`, Propel will use your literal SQL expression, whether it's an alias and column or anything else. That said, I'm not sure that's its intended use.

Comment: It throws exception 'Unknown relation table_b on the TableA table', so I change `table_b` to `TableB` and now it generates the same wrong aliases in SQL select statement as in my example. So it doesn't change anything.

Comment: It works! But it need to be combined with `select` otherwise Propel returns empty objects (no values assigned) and produces a lots of warnings and notices (undefined offsets), but it generates SQL I expected.

BTW the problem occurs even if there is no multiple joins on the same table. Also your hack dosen't seems to work if I try to add  `where` function `(e.g. ->where('a.value_1 = "xxx"')`. Propel uses  `CROSS JOIN` in that situtations, and doesn't use aliases in WHERE clause - weird. More complex conditions still maight be a problem, but `filterByXXX` in `useXXXQuery` works just fine.

Comment: Glad you got it working! See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20127660/propel-translating-the-wrong-table-names to solve the where() problem.

Comment: I get the impression that a lot of this type of behavior is cleaned up in 2.0. Discussions like at https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/pull/182 make me think it could be worth the upgrade.

Comment: @chamberlain your solution for `where` caluse actually works for `select` too. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 4):

I do a little reserch after I read jchamberlain's comment about `where` caluse under his answer and I came to conclusion that

- **you should always use `UpperCamelCase` style when you type column names in propel functions, even though it sometimes works fine if you don't use this style**
- **solution depends on Propel version**

Probably there is no solution for Propel <= 1.6.7 (or maybe raw SQL query is the only solution), because no matter how much I try I always ends up with `Cannot fetch ColumnMap for undefined column: ID_TABLE_B` Propel exception.

For Propel >= 1.6.8 this will work:

If you need **array** with aliased columns as result

```
TableAQuery::create()
  ->useTableBQuery('a')
      // some filters methods
  ->endUse()
  ->useTableBQuery('b')
      // some filters methods
  ->endUse()
  ->select(array('a.Value1', 'b.Value2')) // notice a.value_1 or b.value_2 won't work
  ->find();
```

If you need **objects** with virtual columns from aliased columns

```
TableAQuery::create()
  ->useTableBQuery('a')
      // some filters methods
  ->endUse()
  ->useTableBQuery('b')
      // some filters methods
  ->endUse()
  ->withColumn('a.Value1') // notice a.value_1 won't work
  ->withColumn('b.Value2') // notice b.value_2 won't work
  ->find();
```