# Propel translating the wrong table names

Tags: php, sql, propel

```
            ->joinOrigin('origin')
            ->joinLocation('location', \Criteria::LEFT_JOIN)
            ->where("LOWER(IF(location.code IS NOT NULL,location.code, origin.code)) NOT IN ?", $not_in_old_job_search_array)
```

Is a part of a Propel query I am porting from raw SQL. `location` and `origin` are two foreign keys (declared as such in the schema.xml) which point to the same table. Propel adds the joins properly:

```
INNER JOIN `idb_countries` `origin` 
ON (idb_ads.idb_countries_ididb_origin=origin.ididb_countries) 
LEFT JOIN `idb_countries` `location` 
ON (idb_ads.idb_countries_ididb_job_location=location.ididb_countries)
```

but the where clause comes out like this:

```
LOWER(IF(idb_countries.code IS NOT NULL,idb_countries.code, idb_countries.code)) NOT IN (:p5,:p6,:p7))
```

How can I avoid this?

EDIT: My propel version is 1.7.0, and my php version is 5.4.9

Comment: Just saw your comment on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19524589/472495); would you edit your Propel and PHP versions into the question here?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to click Save...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think yours is a simpler problem than that described at [Propel: selecting columns from aliased join tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19524589/propel-selecting-columns-from-aliased-join-tables/).

Try using this where() call:

```
->where(
    "LOWER(IF(location.Code IS NOT NULL,location.Code, origin.Code)) NOT IN ?",
    $not_in_old_job_search_array
)
```

You'll notice the only difference is that I've changed "code" to "Code". The `where()` method is expecting the PHP name of the column, not the actual column name. The aliases are stored with the PHP name, so "Code" lets it know to use the alias while "code" does not.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Now Propel is generating the following: "WHERE LOWER(IF(location.code IS NOT NULL,location.code, origin.code)) NOT IN  Array" which is still not right, but better.

Comment: Ok, it works perfectly now. I think the Propel query parser is space-sensitive.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I was doing `->useAbcQuery('abc1')->where('...')` and Propel was replacing the alias with the table name in the where block, thus adding a `CROSS JOIN`.  Changing the fields to their "phpName"s fixed this!  Thanks again! :D